# How to use CSS Media Queries on a Retina Screen

Tags: css, media-queries, devicepixelratio

I have written the following media query that is not behaving as expected.  The change is occurring at 1537px not 1024px.  I am using a Retina screen and this code is contained within a SCSS file in a project bootstrapped with create-react-app 3.

I've done some research and found that my device pixel ratio is 3.  Would that effect how I'll need to write my media queries?

My CSS:

```
&--info-container {

  border: 5px solid red;

  @media (max-width: 1024px) {
    border: 5px solid green; 
  }

}
```

In my index.html:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my browser was zoomed into 150%.  Didn't think to check that!!  Zooming out to 100% fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Sounds like what I just experienced, on windows 10 retina screen, it defaults to 150% scaling which messes up a lot of websites

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to target iPads? Device pixels and CSS pixels are different.

Here are two articles that explain that in more detail:
https://medium.com/@flik185/understanding-device-resolution-for-web-design-and-development-3bb4a5183478
https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Here's a quick reference that you might find useful: http://iosres.com/